# Pyrebase query builder python- exec() issue

Tags: python, firebase, pyrebase

Hi there I'm developing a firebase-query builder. It's basically a function that asks for attributes and returns a string with the complete query. It must be executed and should return the data.

```
def Search(**kwargs):
    base="db.child('vocabulary')"

    #AMOUNT OF DATA ENTERED.
    entry_length=(len(kwargs.items()))

    #LAST ATRIBUTTE ENTERED
    last_atributte=list(kwargs.items())[entry_length-1]


    #FOR EVERY ATTRIBUTE, ADD IT TO THE ROOT. IF IT'S THE LAST->CLOSE THE QUERY
    for x,y in kwargs.items():

        if y!=last_atributte[1]:
            base+=".child('{}')".format(y)
        else:
            base+=".child('{}').get().val()".format(y)
    print(base)
    return (base)


query=Search(word_type="verbs",word="play")
print(exec(query))
```

In this example the function is returning this string:
`db.child('vocabulary').child('verbs').child('play').get().val()`

If I run the string above script it returns the data but when I execute it using the exec() in-built returns None:
`print(exec(db.child('vocabulary').child('verbs').child('play').get().val()))`

Do you have a hint how can I improve it? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue there was a wrong string handling.

Instead of:

```
query=Search(word_type="verbs",word="play")
print(exec(query))
```

Which is equivalent to: print(exec(query)). It should be:

```
query=Search(word_type="verbs",word="play")
query="print({})".format(query)
exec(query)
```